# Bash manipulate and sort file content with arrays via loop

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, while-loop

## Purpose

Create a bash script which loops through certain commands and save the outputs of each command *(they print only numbers)* into a file *(I guess the best way is to save them in a file?)* with their dates *(unix time)* next to each output so we can use these stored values next time we run the script and it looped through again, see if there isn't any change in the outputs of commands within the last hour.

## Example output

```sh
# ./script
command1 123123
command2 123123
```

## Important notes

- There are around 200 commands which the script will loop through.
- There'll be new commands in the future so the script will have to check if this command exists in the saved file. If it already present, only compare it within the last hour to see if the number has changed since you last saved the file. If it doesn't exists, save it into the file so we can use it to compare next time.
- Order of the commands which the script will run might be different as the commands increase/decrease/change. So if it's only like this for now;

```sh
# ./script
command1 123123
command2 123123
```

and you add a 3rd command in the future, the order might change (it is also not certain what kind of pattern it's following), for example;

```sh
# ./script
command1 123123
command3 123123
command2 123123
```

so we can't, for example, read it line by line and in this case, I believe the best way is to compare them with the `command*` names.

## Structure for stored values

My presumed structure for stored values is like this (don't have to stick with this one tho);

```sh
command1 123123 unixtime
command2 123123 unixtime
```

## About the said commands

The things I called `commands` are basically applications which are running on `/usr/local/bin/` an can be accessed by directly running their names on the shell, like `command1 getnumber` and it will print you the number.

Since the commands are located in the `/usr/local/bin/` and following a similar pattern, I'm first looping through the `/usr/local/bin/` for `command*`. See below.

```sh
commands=`find /usr/local/bin/ -name 'command*'`

for i in $commands; do
    echo "$i" "`$i getnumber`"
done
```

so this will loop through all files that starts with `command` and run `command* getnumber` for each one, which will print out the numbers we need.

Now we need to store these values in a file to compare them next time we run the command.

### Catch:

We may even run the script every few minutes but we only need to **report if the values *(numbers)* hasn't changed in the last hour**.

The script will list the *numbers* every time you run it and we may add a styling to those who aren't changed in the last hour to pop them out for the eyes, maybe like adding a red color to them?

## Attempt number #1

So this is my first attempt building this script. Here's what it looks like;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

commands=`find /usr/local/bin/ -name 'command*'`
date=`date +%s`

while read -r command number unixtime; do
    for i in $commands; do
        current_block_count=`$i getnumber`
        if [[ $command = $i ]]; then
            echo "$i exists in the file, checking the number changes within last hour" # just for debugging, will be removed in production
            if (( ($date-$unixtime)/60000 > 60 )); then
                if (( $number >= $current_number_count )); then
                    echo "There isn't a change within the last hour, this is a problem!" # just for debugging, will be removed in production
                    echo -e "$i" "`$i getnumber`" "/" "$number" "\e[31m< No change within last hour."
                else
                    echo "$i" "`$i getnumber`"
                    echo "There's a change within the last hour, we're good." # just for debugging, will be removed in production
                    # find the line number of $i so we can change it with the new output
                    line_number=`grep -Fn '$i' outputs.log`
                    new_output=`$i getnumber`
                    sed -i "$line_numbers/.*/$new_output/" outputs.log
                fi
            else
                echo "$i" "`$i getnumber`"
                # find the line number of $i so we can change it with the new output
                line_number=`grep -Fn '$i' outputs.log`
                output_check="$i getnumber; date +%s"
                new_output=`eval ${output_check}`
                sed -i "$line_numbers/.*/$new_output/" outputs.log
            fi
        else
            echo "$i does not exists in the file, adding it now" # just for debugging, will be removed in production
            echo "$i" "`$i getnumber`" "`date +%s`" >> outputs.log
        fi
    done
done < outputs.log
```

Which was a quite the disaster and eventually, it did nothing when I've run it.

## Attempt number #2

This time, I've tried another approach nesting `for loop` outside of the `while loop`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

commands=`find /usr/local/bin/ -name 'command*'`
date=`date +%s`


for i in $commands; do
    echo "${i}" "`$i getnumber`"
    name=${i}
    number=`$i getnumber`
    unixtime=$date
    echo "$name" "$number" "$unixtime" # just for debugging, will be removed in production
    while read -r command number unixtime; do
        if ! [ -z ${name+x} ]; then
            echo "$name" "$number" "$unix" >> outputs.log
        else
            if [[ $name = $i ]]; then
                if (( ($date-$unixtime)/60000 > 60 )); then
                    if (( $number >= $current_number_count )); then
                        echo "There isn't a change within the last hour, this is a problem!" # just for debugging, will be removed in production
                        echo -e "$i" "`$i getnumber`" "/" "$number" "\e[31m< No change within last hour."
                    else
                        echo "$i" "`$i getnumber`"
                        echo "There's a change within the last hour, we're good." # just for debugging, will be removed in production
                        # find the line number of $i so we can change it with the new output
                        line_number=`grep -Fn '$i' outputs.log`
                        new_output=`$i getnumber`
                        sed -i "$line_numbers/.*/$new_output/" outputs.log
                    fi
                else
                    echo "$i" "`$i getnumber`"
                    # find the line number of $i so we can change it with the new output
                    line_number=`grep -Fn '$i' outputs.log`
                    output_check="$i getnumber; date +%s"
                    new_output=`eval ${output_check}`
                    sed -i "$line_numbers/.*/$new_output/" outputs.log
                fi
            else
                echo "$i does not exists in the file, adding it now" # just for debugging, will be removed in production
                echo "$i" "`$i getnumber`" "`date +%s`" >> outputs.log
            fi
        fi
    done < outputs.log
done
```

Unfortunately, no luck for me, again.

Can someone give me a helping hand?

## Additional notes #2

So basically, you run the script first time, `outputs.log` is empty, so you write the outputs of commands into `outputs.log`.

And it's been 10 minutes passed, you run the script again, since it's only 10 minutes passed and not more than an hour, the script won't check if the numbers have changed or not. It will not manipulate the stored values but also display us the outputs of command every time you run it. *(Their present outputs and not from the stored values)*

In this 10 minutes timeframe, for example, there might have been new commands added so it will check if the commands' outputs are stored every time you run the script, just to deal with new commands.

Now it's been, let's say 1.2 hours passed, you decided to run the script again, this time the script will check if the numbers hasn't changed after more than an hour and report us saying that `Hey! It's been more than an hour passed and those numbers still haven't changed, there might be problem!`

## Simple explanation

- You have 100 commands to run, your script will loop through each of them and do the followings for each;
- Run the script whenever you want
- On each run, check if `outputs.log` contains the command

  - If `outputs.log` contains the commands of each loop, check the last stored date ($unixtime) of each of them.

    - If last stored date is more than an hour, check the numbers between the current run and the stored value

      - If the numbers haven't changed for more than an hour, run the command in red text color.
      - If the numbers have changed, run the command as usual without any warning.
    - If last stored date is less than an hour, run the command as usual.
  - If `outputs.log` doesn't contain the command, simply store them in the file so it can be used for next runs to check.

Comment: Do you only care if the most recent output is different from the last time a command was run, or if it's different from any previous run in the last hour?

Comment: Do you have an initial version of outputs.log? You can put "set -x" at the front of the script to get a trace of what's being executed, which might help.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to mention that. I don’t have an initial version of the logs and I’m hoping to make the script create one itself.

Comment: Basically I want it to store those values not every time I run but if only the last saved values are older than 1 hour.

Comment: I felt like my question wasn't that clear so I've added some additional notes and a simpler explanation. Can you guys please check?

Answer (score 0):

The following uses a sqlite database to store results, instead of a flat file, which makes querying the history of previous runs easy:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

database=tracker.db

if [ ! -e "$database" ]; then
    sqlite3 -batch "$database" <<EOF
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS outputs(command TEXT
                                 , output INTEGER
                                 , ts INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime('%s', 'now')));
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS outputs_idx ON outputs(command, ts);
EOF
fi

for cmd in /usr/local/bin/command*; do
    f=$(basename "$cmd")
    o=$("$cmd")
    echo "$f $o"
    sqlite3 -batch "$database" <<EOF
INSERT INTO outputs(command, output) VALUES ('$f', $o);
SELECT command || ' has unchanged output!'
FROM outputs
WHERE command = '$f' AND ts >= strftime('%s', 'now', '-1 hour')
GROUP BY command
HAVING count(DISTINCT output) = 1 AND count(*) > 1;
EOF
done
```

It lists commands that have had every run in the last hour produce the same output (and skips commands that have only run once). If instead you're interested in cases where the most recent output of each command is the same as the previous run in that hour timeframe, replace the sqlite3 invocation in the loop with:

```
sqlite3 -batch $database <<EOF
INSERT INTO outputs(command, output) VALUES ('$f', $o);
WITH prevs AS
 (SELECT command
       , output
       , row_number() OVER w AS rn
       , lead(output, 1) OVER w AS prev
  FROM outputs
  WHERE command = '$f' AND ts >= strftime('%s', 'now', '-1 hour')
  WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts DESC))
SELECT command || ' has unchanged output!'
FROM prevs
WHERE output = prev AND rn = 1;
EOF
```

(This requires the `sqlite3` shell from release 3.25 or newer because it uses features introduced then.)

Comment: I’m not really familiar working with databases but I’ll give this one a try. Thank you.

Comment: How can I add a parameter to the command this script runs? Because the commands should follow a `getnumber` parameter to execute. They will not run if you only run the commands itself. It should run something like this; `/usr/local/bin/command* getnumber` to give us an output.

Comment: @MarryJane You just add any needed arguments to the expression that runs the command.